# how to secure my Iterator so that it throws a exception if it points on .end()

Tags: c++

I wrote this `Vector` class and one nested `Iterator` class and one `const_Iterator` class, now I have to secure my `Vector` so my `Iterator` doesn't point beyond `.end()` with for instance my `operator ++` method and to throw an exception if i try.
so in my `iterator` class I cannot access `.end()` because its a vector method. so I was thinking, instead of pointing on values in my `Iterator` class I point on the whole vector  but i cannot access `.end()` with a `Vector*` .
Am I on the right way to the solution and if I am how can I pass my Vector so I can use it in the way I intend to?

```
class Vector{
      public:
        using value_type= double;
        using size_type= size_t;
        using difference_type= ptrdiff_t;
        using reference = double&;
        using const_reference= const double&;
        using pointer = double*;
        using const_pointer= const double*;
        using iterator = double*;
        using const_iterator= const double*;
    private:
     size_t sz;
     size_t max_sz;
     double* values=nullptr;
    class const_Iterator{
            public:
                using value_type = double;
                using difference_type = ptrdiff_t;
                using reference = double&;
                using pointer = double*;
                using iterator_category = std::forward_iterator_tag;
            private:
            double* ptr;
            size_t cnt;
            public:
                const_Iterator(double* p){
                    ptr=p;
                    cnt=0;

                 }
                 const_Iterator& operator++ () {
                    ptr++;
                    cnt = 0;
                    return *this;
                }
                bool  operator==(const const_Iterator& rop)const {
                    return this->ptr == rop.ptr;
                }

                bool  operator!=(const const_Iterator& rop)const {
                    return this->ptr != rop.ptr;
                }
                const double operator* () const {
                    return *ptr;
                }
                friend Vector::difference_type operator-(const Vector::const_Iterator& lop,const Vector::const_Iterator& rop) {
                    return lop.ptr-rop.ptr;
                }
        };
            class Iterator{
            public: 
                using value_type = double;
                using difference_type = ptrdiff_t;
                using reference = double&;
                using pointer = double*;
                using iterator_category = std::forward_iterator_tag;
            private:
            double* ptr;
            size_t cnt;
            public:
                Iterator(double* p){
                    ptr=p;
                    cnt=0;

                 }
                 Iterator& operator++() {
                    ptr++;
                    cnt = 0;
                    return *this;
                }
                Iterator operator++(int){
                    Iterator a(ptr);
                    ptr++;
                    return a;
                }
                bool operator==( Iterator& rop) {
                    return this->ptr != rop.ptr;
                }

                bool operator!=(const Iterator& rop) {
                    return this->ptr != rop.ptr;
                }
                double& operator*() {
                    return *ptr;
                }
                 operator const_Iterator() const{

                 return const_Iterator(ptr);
                 }; 



                 };
const_Iterator end() const{return const_Iterator(values+sz);}    
const_Iterator  begin() const{return const_Iterator(values);}
   Iterator begin()  { return values; }
   Iterator end()  { return values + sz; }
        size_t min_sz = 5;
        Vector();
        Vector(size_t);
        Vector(const Vector&);
        Vector (initializer_list<double> ); 
        void push_back(double);
        void reserve(size_t);
        void pop_back();
        bool empty();
        void clear();
        Vector&  operator=(const Vector&);
        const double& operator[] (size_t) const;
        double& operator[] (size_t) ;

        void fit_to_shrink();
        size_t size()const {return sz;}
        ostream& print(ostream&) const;
};
```

Comment: What do you mean by _i cannot access .end() with a Vector*_? Of course you can (`vector->end()`)!

Comment: Why can't you do `this->end()` to get the iterator from the vector?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your iterator may look like:

```
class Iterator{
public:
    // ... using type

private:
    Vector* parent;
    std::size_t index;
public:
    Iterator(Vector& v, std::size_t index) : ptr(&v), index(index) {}

     Iterator& operator++() {
       if (index == parent->size()) {
           throw std::runtime_error("++ on end iterator");
       }
        ++index;
        return *this;
    }

    Iterator operator++(int){
        Iterator old(*this);
        ++(*this);
        return old;
    }

    bool operator==(const Iterator& rhs) const {
        if (parent != rhs.parent) {
            throw std::runtime_error("You compare iterator of different containers");
        }
        return index == rhs.index;
    }

    bool operator!=(const Iterator& rop) const { return !(*this == rhs); }

    double& operator*() { return parent->at(index); } // `at` throws on invalid index

    // ...

 };
```

And your vector:

```
Iterator Vector::begin() { return Iterator(this, 0);}
Iterator Vector::end() { return Iterator(this, size());}
```